# Tiles with XSLT - Struts 2

Tags: xml, xslt, struts2, tiles

My application is using Struts2 and Tiles for the Front End. Now , I need to modify the HTML using XSLT

In the struts.xml, am redirecting the action result to a tiles files and it is rendering a JSP file.

Now what I want to do is, I want to render the pages, after applying XSLT. The XSLT is not in a physical file, and its in the DB as a string.

How to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do this. But to provide some useful code I'll put it in this answer field.

Other than using tiles xml you can also programmaticlly create definitions (an example of this will be provided later).  It is even possible to use a new struts2 result type: here is a discussion of that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3937 (along with code to that effect).

It is possible to use a ViewPreparer with tiles: http://tiles.apache.org/framework/apidocs/org/apache/tiles/preparer/ViewPreparer.html

The execute method of the view preparer is "Method associated to a tile and called immediately before the tile is included." this sounds like something you would want.

So you might be able to just create a view perparer and just stick to xml. But it is nice when testing things to be able to programmaticlly set things up (possibly to test) rather than stick to xml definitions this code has been included to that effect it does NOT have any thing to do with a viewperparer currently (although I should think that could be remedied).

```
package com.kenmcwilliams.employmentsystem.action.test;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.tiles.Attribute;
import org.apache.tiles.Definition;
import org.apache.tiles.TilesContainer;
import org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess;
import org.apache.tiles.mgmt.MutableTilesContainer;
import org.apache.tiles.request.ApplicationContext;
import org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest;
import org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletUtil;

/**
 *
 * @author ken
 */
@Result(type = "tiles", location = "dynamic-tiles-definition")
public class DynamicTilesDefinition extends ActionSupport {

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = ServletUtil.getApplicationContext(context);
        TilesContainer container = TilesAccess.getContainer(applicationContext);
        if (container instanceof MutableTilesContainer) {
        } else {
            throw new Exception("A Mutable Tiles Container is required [TODO: Write example web.xml code example]");
        }
        MutableTilesContainer mc = (MutableTilesContainer) container;
        Definition def = new Definition();

        Attribute templateAttribute = Attribute.createTemplateAttribute("/WEB-INF/test/test-template.jsp");
        def.setTemplateAttribute(templateAttribute);
        def.putAttribute("body", new Attribute("/WEB-INF/test/test-dynamic-definition.jsp"));
        def.setName("dynamic-tiles-definition");

        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
        ServletRequest servletRequest = new ServletRequest(applicationContext, request, response);

        mc.register(def, servletRequest);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```